# Selectively Force Browser Cache to Clear Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, caching, backbone.js

There are a lot of answers out there for browser caching but most are about either turning caching on or off or requesting using a different url for some static asset like js or images.

- I am loading json data over an ajax request
- This is dynamic content, say a list of tasks
- I only want to update when a user has done a certain action. Until then it can be cached forever.
- When the user takes that action, I want to invalidate the cache and get a new version from the server.

  1. Is there a way to clear the browsers local cache without changing the url. So, /tasks is cached until next year. I want to invalidate that and force future requests to /tasks to get new data and a new expires header.
  2. Would I be better off not allowing browser caching and cache the requests/data on the server instead?

Another similar question:
[Forcing AJAX request to revalidate cache with server, without reloading completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308953/forcing-ajax-request-to-revalidate-cache-with-server-without-reloading-complete)

Comment: Isn't it easier to use localStorage/Sessionstorage to store the data, and when the user does a action clear that store and get a new from the server?

Comment: @VeldMuijz - Yea that is a great suggestion. I might be able to leverage that! Thanks. I would also like to know what people have to say about the two questions I have though for future reference

Answer (score -1):

foreach request with `cache: false` jquery will add a timestamp as a get paramater, so the request is unique and won't be cached

```
$.ajax({
    url:"example.php"
    cache:false
});
```

referring to the [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/): 
cache (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp')
Type: Boolean
If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL that has already been requested by a GET.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the url must be the same. I am aware of this functionality. Please see the first line of the question.